# ntpd doesn't sync with W32Time, ntpdate does

Tags: sync, ntpd

I have QNX 6.5 with `ntpd` running. I try to use Windows W32Time service as an ntp-server. When I use `ntpdate 192.168.x.x`, it works fine.  But `ntpd` daemon won't sync.

`ntpq` says that server is reached (`377`):

```
# ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 192.168.x.x   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx    2 u    5    8  377    0.770  480979.   2.500
```

But it hasn't chosen it for sync: it should be `*192.168.x.x`, but it is `192.168.x.x`.

---

**`ntpd -g -d` log:**

```
transmit: at 1777 192.168.y.y->192.168.x.x mode 3 len 48
receive: at 1777 192.168.y.y<-192.168.x.x mode 4 len 48
clock_filter: n 8 off 480.927703 del 0.005295 dsp 0.015682 jit 0.002299
transmit: at 1785 192.168.y.y->192.168.x.x mode 3 len 48
receive: at 1785 192.168.y.y<-192.168.x.x mode 4 len 48
clock_filter: n 8 off 480.925317 del 0.002604 dsp 0.015682 jit 0.003625
transmit: at 1793 192.168.y.y->192.168.x.x mode 3 len 48
receive: at 1793 192.168.y.y<-192.168.x.x mode 4 len 48
clock_filter: n 8 off 480.927255 del 0.008042 dsp 0.015682 jit 0.001629
```

---

I know that the offset might be too big. But I still need it to be synched (especially if there is a big offset). And it works well with other ntp-servers (not windows w32time), so I don't think offset is an issue.

Why my time is not synched, and how can I get `ntpd` to sync properly?